Is there a ruby/Puma.rb equivalent to Apache HTTPD's "SSLClientVerify optional" setting?
My team is considering removing apache httpd as a reverse proxy for our Ruby on Rails app and relying only on the puma app server.
However the first obstacle is the business need to support HTTPD's "SSLClientVerify optional" setting. I didn't realize this is not a feature of the OpenSSL library unless I missed something. Is it possible to do an equivalent using the puma.rb app server?

Seems like setting the :verify_mode to "peer" might be the option you are looking for? OpenSSL Docs. Here is a configuration example.

Thanks for the example! I'm reading the docs as saying verify_mode: 'peer' will terminate the connection, which is not what is desired.
